# vba speed up performance

Tags: vba, performance, loops, for-loop

currently the code is looking through 7000+ rows.

Im having problems with it crashing.

can anyone help with enhancing performance. Im very new to VBA

would use of arrays here be useful- If so, please help out

```
  Dim mrow As Long, ARow As Long, i As Long
Dim AG_Label As String, M_Label As String
Dim Count As Integer
Dim AG_sht As Worksheet, M_sht As Worksheet

    Set AG_sht = Worksheets("AG")
    Set M_sht = Worksheets("Mappings")
    Set SNL_sht = Worksheets("SNL")



    Count = 2

    ARow = AG_sht.Range("B" & Sheets("AG").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To ARow
        AG_Label = AG_sht.Cells(i, "N").Value
        On Error Resume Next
        mrow = M_sht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'For j = 2 To mrow
            'M_Match_1 = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "P").Value
            M_Label = M_sht.Cells(Count, "C").Value

            If AG_Label = M_Label And M_sht.Cells(Count, "L").Value = "FRY-9C" Then
                M_sht.Cells(Count, "J").copy
                AG_sht.Cells(i, "AM").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                  Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
                    If i = ARow Then
                        Count = Count + 1
                        M_Label = Count
                        If mrow <> "" Then
                            i = 2
                        If Count = mrow Then Exit For
                        End If
                     End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next

    Call match2

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` somewhere outside the posted code? Otherwise that's always a good place to start.

Comment: *currently the code is looking through 7000+ rows*...and doing what with the rows? Provide full explained context. Also, there is an unknown function being called, *match2*.

Comment: how about if you eliminate the crashing first, then work on the performance .... start by telling us where it crashes and which error shows up

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code. it is all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate time saver I would recommend is instead of looping through using a copy/paste, look into how to assign values to your destination column. Something like:

```
If AG_Label = M_Label And M_sht.Cells(Count, "L").Value = "FRY-9C" Then
            M_sht.Cells(Count, "J").Value = AG_sht.Cells(i, "AM").Value
        End If
```

I think the copy/paste is causing a lot of the inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I have the below base function that I call anytime I enter a screen sensitive function or SUb with "FAST" and when exiting with "NORMAL". THis is great and solve all my performance issues

'
'Toggle Excel performance On or OFF
'This function is used to switch on and off the base XL calculation that allow performance when managing layout and
'calculation. The calculatefull option is not in this function as it may be driven in detail by the caller
'
Sub SetHighPerformance(perf_mode As String)

```
If perf_mode = "NORMAL" Then 'Set user setting back in place

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = True
Else
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
End If
```

End Sub